# How to place graphics/image/figure after a paragraph

Tags: graphics, positioning, sections-paragraphs

I have hacked together a small command that I can use to include graphics, scale them as I want and create a label for it and reference to it.

I use it like this:

```
As can be seen from
 \screencap{voltage-regulation}{Voltage Regulation Circuitry}.
the input is proteced against reverse polarity by the diode D1
and from thence the internal nominally 24 VDC voltage is derived with 
the pre-regulator U8/LM317.
```

The command is

```
\newcommand{\screencap}[2] {
\begin{figure}[htb] 
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{#1.png}
\caption{#2}
\label{fig:#1}
\end{figure}
figure~\ref{fig:#1}
}
```

And it renders like this:

[image]

This is almost good enough but I don't want the image to appear in the middle of the paragraph.  But after it, or basically anywhere after the place I refer to it but not inside the paragraph.

Comment: separate the command in to two and place the figure between paragraphs and the `\ref` where you refer to it. That is the standard latex markup, and does what you want  here.

Comment: Note also you are missing `%` at ends of line in your definition (which is why your image shows a spurious space before the **.** after 4.1

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `h` specifier from the figure placement options? Does `\begin{figure}[tb]` produce better results?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Two commands is what I had previously and that of course works but that was specifically what I tried to avoid cause it is more work and repetitive and goes against my programmer instinct of "do not repeat yourseld" or "single point of truth".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the %  / space tip, I did not know about that.

Comment: @gernot Thanks, removing 'h' did cause the figure to float further in the document but it caused it to appear at the top of the next page (probably the 't' specifier). Removing all specifiers seems like the best option though it seems like it leaves the images at the end of the section, not the paragraph.

Comment: Most programmers would not call using the same name in a variable definition and its reference "repeating yourself"  `\label{foo}` defines  `\r@foo` (and can only appear once), `\ref{foo}` accesses the value of `\r@foo` (and may appear any number of times). By conflating these two you obscure the markup and lose functionality as you can no longer control the location of the reference and the location of the referenced item separately.

Comment: In may document classes (all the standard ones) `\section` does not force a page break, so the figure may float beyond the end of the section.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle after 40 years of daily programming I guess I'm not "most programmers" ;)  I get your point and technically you are correct. However repeating the name twice helps me none and introduces the possibility of errors and most of the time I only need to reference the picture once. So why repeat it? I can still refer to it multiple times if I need to. So I don't think I loose anything.

Comment: well latex does not support floating a figure to the end of the paragraph (and it is really not that easy to add in any compatible way) so you lose the layout  control that you get with the standard markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, thanks, not the answer I was hoping for but good to know so I won't waste time on chasing it.¨